# Implemente um programa que receba um nome e apresente apenas o último nome e o 1º nome

Tags: python

Eu fiz ele desse jeito:

```
nome=input('Digite seu nome completo:').title()
lista=nome.split()
print(lista)
print(lista[-1],',',lista[0])
```

Porem na hora de imprimir fica assim:

`Fulano , Ciclano`

Gostaria de ele ficar assim sem esse espaço no meio:

```
Fulano, Ciclano
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use o `+` em vez da vírgula em `lista[-1]` que terá o resultado esperado:

```
nome=input('Digite seu nome completo:').title()
lista=nome.split()
print(lista)
print(lista[-1] + ', ' + lista[0])
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Quando imprime multiplos elementos com `print` a função já separa todos eles por espaço, no entanto, você tem formas mais apropriadas de controlar a formatação do que escreve na tela.

Uma delas é utilizando as mais recentes [*f-string*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings), desde que tenha uma versão do python igual ou superior à 3.6:

```
print(f'{lista[-1]}, {lista[0]}')
```

Fica mais legível, especialmente se tiver vários valores que queira mostrar, com formatações especificas.

Se estiver a trabalhar numa versão mais antiga pode utilizar [*string format*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) que é semelhante ainda que não tão intuitivo:

```
print('{}, {}'.format(lista[-1], lista[0]))
```

Comment: muito obrigado!